# react context: it is printing empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass the value I set in setting.js and pass it to all my child by using react  context concept.

Below are all my codes.

thingscontext.js ( this is where I create my context object)

```
import React from "react";

const ThingsContex = React.createContext({});

export const ThingsProvider = ThingsContex.Provider;

export default ThingsContex;
```

setting.js (my custom provider)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ChildOne from "./Child_One";
import ChildTwo from "./Child_Two";
import { ThingsProvider } from "./thingscontext";

function Setting() {
  const [starttime, setStartTime] = useState(8);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Setting</h2>
      <ThingsProvider value={starttime}>
        <ChildOne />
        <ChildTwo />
      </ThingsProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Setting;
```

Child_one.js (this is where I want to call print out the value)

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ThingsContext from "./thingscontext";

function ChildOne() {
  const things = useContext(ThingsContext);

  console.log("things ", things);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child One</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChildOne;
```

**Expected result**: to print out the value pass from setting

**Actual result**  : empty object

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-vignt?file=/components/Child_One.js:0-281), simply navigate to ChildOne page and open console, it will show that it is printing empty object. any help is appreciated

Comment: `ChildOne` is not inside the context provider if you click the "ChildOne" link. The context provider is in "Settings". And when you click "Settings" the console does put out `things 8`.

Comment: how do I make childOne and childTwo insdie context provider, so that they can access values from setting.js

Comment: Move the `<ThingsProvider value={starttime}>` to `index,js` so that the whole router can be inside of it. Then any page in that router can access that context.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to `/childOne` route, react router renders this line of code from `index.js`

```
      <Route path="/childone" component={ChildOne} />
```

`ChildOne` in this line isn't a child of Context Provider, therefore its default value `{}` is logged. (because you created the context as `React.createContext({})`.

If you navigate to `/setting` you see the desired result.